# Ubuntu: vim gruvbox looks like completely different in tmux

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux, colors, vimrc

I am a beginner of using tmux and am trying to get vim and tmux working together properly. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, vim 8.1.3741, tmux 3.0a.

All was well until I entered vim inside of a tmux session. The colors looked completely different. I am using gruvbox in vim as shown below.

[image: Current vim settings]

Inside of tmux, it looks like this:

[image: tmux vim]

I have tried adding `set t_ut=` and `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color` inside my `.vimrc` and `.tmux.conf` files respectively. Inside tmux, doing `echo $TERM` gives me `xterm-256color` yet the color is still this yellow.

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `:set bg=dark`?